# Difficulty getting HF filter to work: maybe PCB layout?

Tags: filter, troubleshooting, hf

I am trying to build a set of HF filters using the values from the [Alex filters from HPSDR](https://openhpsdr.org/alex.php). I'm having difficulty getting the input impedance to be 50Ω as it should. Based on wide variations in measuring capacitance before and after installation, I'm wondering if my PCB layout may be to blame.

The layout is a simple one-sided affair, which I'm making a prototype in the basement:

[image]

And here's the schematic (I've added pads for up to 4 capacitors in parallel, and 1x4 headers at the ends.)

[image]

I don't have any fancy test equipment, but I do have a RixExpert antenna analyzer, and testing it against some parts in the parts bins, it's accurate as long as I pick a frequency where the impedance magnitude is around 50Ω. For this 1200pF capacitor I'm testing, I used 2.7MHz. Here's the test setup:

[image]

I pulled the inductors out of the board so I can measure across each of the capacitors. Most of them are pretty close, but for 2 of them, not so. Testing the capacitor in the pictures above (the one near "L10") soldered directly to the testing jig, I read 1205pF, just 5pF off the expected value. Soldering *the same capacitor* to the board as in the picture, I read 1556pF.

I've checked the board for shorts multiple times and found none. Any ideas on what explains my observations?

Comment: 1. I assume there's no copper on the back side of the board? 2. Did you do a sensitivity simulation to see how much the impedance varies with small changes in component values? Even 1% changes might muck things up with a high-order filter like that.

Comment: You may need copper screening "walls" between the inductors?

Comment: @ThePhoton Correct, no copper other side. I didn't do a sensitivity simulation but ostensibly the designer of this circuit did. The BOM specifies 5% parts, which is what I'm using.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Maybe, but what baffles me is the wide variance in the measured capacitance on and off the board. Even with no inductors installed.

Comment: I'm sure you fitted an output load of 50 ohms when you measured the input impedance?

Comment: @Andyaka yes. Though playing with it more, I think maybe it is the layout. I redid it with just traces about as big as the pads connecting the nets, instead of the poly fills, and things seem more reasonable. I wonder if the loops formed where the fill goes between the pads was making a mutual inductance significant to couple across the capacitors? Seems odd, but it's the best explanation this amateur has.

Comment: At 2.7 Meg I don't really see that as an issue but good luck. Oh I see where you mean now - thought it was just bad artwork.

Comment: @Andyaka Well I made it, so it probably is bad :) I'd had some success building more of these where I just cut apart sections with a rotary tool, no etching. Those worked better. I just finished 2.0 with the new layout, and it's still not great but I may be on to new problems now.

Comment: @PhilFrost you could try blobbing solder around what might be a rogue shorted turn though I'm struggling with it at such a low frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a subsequent iteration of the board I realized etching the board was unnecessary work for a prototype, and I could just isolate the sections with an abrasive wheel. Once I did this I got reasonable measurements on and off board.

I think it's the "loop" that's formed around the capacitor pads causing the issue:

[image]

I'm guessing this was somehow acting as a turn of a transformer and coupling with adjacent sections or the components soldered across them.